# Whats Difference Between (Protected / Partial) & (Friend / Shared) & (Sub / Function) on VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I find examples online of VB.NET watch some functions use:

```
    (Protected / Partial) & (Friend / Shared) & (Sub / Function) exp()
    End (Sub / Function)
```

My question what is the difference?

Comment: Read this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @asawyer Useful, except that it's the wrong language ;)

Comment: @ReedCopsey And wrong version. Woops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are actually different, somewhat unrelated items.

`Public`, `Protected`, `Private`, and `Friend` are [Access Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx), which determine who can  "see" or use your method.

`Partial` is used to split the declaration of a type across multiple files.  See [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx) for details.

`Sub` and `Function` define procedures.  [Sub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha) procedures do not return values, where [Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6) procedures return a value.

You'd typically combine one access level with one procedure definition, hence `Private Sub` or `Public Function`, etc.

Comment: For completeness, `Shared` allows elements of a class or structure to be accessed without an actual instance of the object. See [Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) for details.